# Django Forms: styling forms (checkboxes) manually - Input to be outside of label

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I need to render checkbox `form fields` in the following format in html template:

```
<input id="tag" type="checkbox" name="check" value="1">
<label for="tag">Tag 1</label>
```

Currently, in my template I tried:

```
{{ filter.form.tags.errors }}
{% for field in filter.form.tags %}
<input id="{{ field.id_for_label }}" type="checkbox" name="check">
<label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.value }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

This will not render `{{ field.value }}` (I get empty instead of Tag 1) and also is non sticky.

I also tried:

```
{% for field in filter.form.tags %}
{{ field.label_tag }}
{{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Which gives me nested of `<label><input></input></label>`, but displays everything that I need.

Is it possible to render a form such that I get the format that I'm after? (It should also preserve `checked` e.g. make ticks sticky).

---

**Edit:**

```
class TaskFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    """Filter for books by author"""
    tags = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Task.tags.most_common())
    title = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='title', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['tags', 'title']
```

**views.py**

```
def task_list_filter(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = AdditionalForm(request.GET)
        # process the form
        results = Task.objects.all().order_by('-created')

    f = TaskFilter(request.GET, queryset=results)

    # Output final query set
    results = f.qs[0:100]  # only get first 100 objects

    # Create pagination

    # Get the view

    return render(request, 'base/task_list_filter.html', {'filter': f,
                                                    'task_list': results,
                                                    'form': form })
```

Answer (score 3):

To make sure the checkbox is in the correct state you can use the example you yourself provided with a few changes:

```
{% for field in filter.form.tags %}
<input type="checkbox" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}"
       name="{{ field.html_name }}"
       {% if field.value %}checked{% endif %}>
<label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.value }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

And remember that you can use the `{{ field.label_tag }}` to generate the entire label HTML tag.

Comment: This code returns that `{{ field.value }}` as empty, and I simply get checkboxes without actual tag names. Rendering `filter.form.as_p` is fine, but it doesn't work with my styling. The GET request after submitting the form is: `?tags=3&tags=1&tags=2&tags=4` where these are values in appropriate `input` tags.

Comment: Can you post your view and your form then because I feel like something else is not working. `{{ field.value }}` should display `True` or `False` in this case. And if you really wanted to show the label tag (I'm not sure why did you even put field's value within the label tag), you are limited to using `{{ field.label_tag }}` or writing your own label text manually.

Comment: I'm using the `django-filter` library to create the form of tags from `django-taggit`. I will update my question shortly

Comment: Added the edit. I took away some pieces of code, but the main problem is with the `filter.form` not rendering properly.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML

```
{% for field in filter.form.tags %}
{{ field.tag }}  <!-- Generates the checkbox for the field -->
{{ field.choice_label }}  <!-- Generates the named label of the field -->
{% endfor %}
```

I learned that from [this guy](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/28/how-to-filter-querysets-dynamically.html) who has lots of helpful information specific to using Django.